# Single API to upload all files vs Multiple API calls for each file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a nodejs API to upload student certificates for a batch (which can have up to 200 students). I'm confused with the REST API design, should I make an API to handle all the files in a single API or should I make an API to upload a single file at a time and call this API for each certificate in the batch? If I go with the first approach then what should I do In case there is an error in the say 130th pdf? Is there any standard for such API design?

Comment: You could have both the functionality for flexibility.  But then it also depends on the complexity and use case.  If you know you are always going to do batch operations only, then do not implement single-file-operations. Before implementing bulk-operations make sure you really need them. Check this link : https://www.mscharhag.com/api-design/bulk-and-batch-operations

Comment: Note, if you support `multipart/form-data` as the content-type, you can accept one or multiple files via the same API just by how many are present in the data.